# VBA - How to use Mid Substring to get characters backward?

Tags: excel, vba, substring

Good day everyone,

I am working with Excel VBA.
I want to be able to extract the amount and unit from below examples.

Example

1. Peter sell 1kt Gold to James
2. Lester sell 20kt Silver to Maya
3. Aplh sell 300kb of Liquid Nitrogen to Liz
4. Beth sell to Carl 40kb of Palm Oil

Expected Result

```
Amt Unit
1   kt
20  kt
300 kb
40  kb
```

Becuz the amount can vary, I thought of using the substring method "Mid".
I get the position of "kt" or "kb", then go backwards by getting the previous char.
if it is a number, I keep going backwards until I find a space.

But it seems you cannot use Mid to go backwards as I got an error:

```
'Get Unit and Amount
id = "kt"
pos1 = InStr(examples, id)

Dim subAmt1 As String
subAmt1 = Mid(examples, pos1, -1)
```

I also tried this, but I get an empty string instead of a number

```
subAmt1 = Mid(examples, pos1 - 2, 1)
```

I read there is a StrReverse() method, but is that the only way?
I'm pretty sure Java Substring can use negative index to get char backwards, I dunno about VBA though.
Does anybody have a better solution for this?

Much Appreciated

Comment: Yes, there is a reverse `InStr` function. [InStrRev](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instrrev-function)

Comment: @user2741620 Five answers with more than five different working approaches - feel free to mark your preferred one as correct. Acceptance is indicated by a green coloured checkmark next to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Just one way to do it - Happy new year to come

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoIt()
    Dim s As String
    s = "Peter sell 1kt Gold to James"
    Debug.Print GetIt(s)
    s = "Aplh sell 300kb of Liquid Nitrogen to Liz"
    Debug.Print GetIt(s)
End Sub

Private Function GetIt(theLIne As String) As String
    Dim v, r
    Dim what As String
    If InStr(theLIne, "kb") Then
        what = "kb"
    Else
        If InStr(theLIne, "kt") Then
            what = "kt"
        Else
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    v = Split(theLIne, what)
    r = v(0)
    v = Split(r, " ")
    r = v(UBound(v))
    GetIt = r & " " & what
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Regular Expressions` in `VBA`.

Read the code comments and BE SURE to set the Reference as noted in the comments, or recode to use late binding.

***Data** (in a named range Named "Statements")*
*with two adjacent columns*
[image]

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

'Set reference to Microsoft VBScrip Regular Expressions 5.5
'   or could use late binding
Sub GetIt()
    Dim rSrc As Range, rDest As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection
    Dim I As Long
    
'Many ways to get range to process
'Here I am using a Named range that I set up on some worksheet
    Set rSrc = ThisWorkbook.Names("Statements").RefersToRange

'processing in a vba array is much faster than multiple calls to worksheet
    vSrc = rSrc
    
'create results array
    ReDim vRes(0 To UBound(vSrc, 1), 1 To 2)

'Headers
    vRes(0, 1) = "Amt"
    vRes(0, 2) = "Unit"
    
'Initialize regular expression and process the table
Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Global = False
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "(\d+)\s*(kt|kb)\b"
    For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
        If .Test(vSrc(I, 1)) Then
            Set MC = .Execute(vSrc(I, 1))
            vRes(I, 1) = MC(0).SubMatches(0)
            vRes(I, 2) = MC(0).SubMatches(1)
        Else
            vRes(I, 1) = "none"
        End If
    Next I
End With

Set rDest = rSrc.Offset(rowoffset:=-1, columnoffset:=1).Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, columnsize:=2)
With rDest
    .ClearContents
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Style = "Output"
End With
    
End Sub
```

***Results***
[image]

If you have `365` you can also do this with a worksheet formula:

If your phrases are in a range named `Statements`, then this formula in some cell:

```
=LET(
    amt, TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(Statements, {"kb", "kt"}), " ", -1),
    unit, MID(
        Statements,
        BYROW(
            Statements,
            LAMBDA(arr, MIN(SEARCH({"kb", "kt"}, arr & "kbkt")))
        ),
        2
    ),
    hdr, {"Amt", "Unit"},
    VSTACK(hdr, HSTACK(amt, unit))
)
```

will return:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might try an approach via `Split()`

- analyzing **only** elements containing letter *"k"* after a positive `Filter()` by blank delimiters,
- checking for a digit as starter and
- returning the found element immediately having broken it in a numeric part via `Val()` and the wanted unit to the right:

```
Private Function GetIt(theLIne As String) As String
'Note: assumes units of same size 2 and containing letter "k"
Const SIZE As Long = 2
    Dim v As Variant
    v = Filter(Split(theLIne), "k")     ' check only elements containing "k"
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
        If Left(v(i), 1) Like "#" Then  ' isolate element with starting digit
            GetIt = Val(v(i)) & "|" & Right(v(i), SIZE)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

**Alternative for MS 365**

*Uses a `TextAfter()` evaluation (vers. MS 365), here using a loop over both delimiters instead of a one-go approach above:*

```
Function getIt365(ByVal theLine As String) As String
    Dim ids As Variant
    ids = Array("kb", "kt")
    Dim id As Variant
    For Each id In ids
        Dim pos As Long
        pos = InStr(theLine, id)
        If pos Then
            getIt365 = Evaluate("textafter(""" & Left(theLine, pos - 1) & ""","" "",-1)") & "|" & id
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next id
End Function
```

**Addition: What is the actual issue in your posted code?**

The 3rd argument in VBA's `Mid()` function indicating the wanted (rest) length has to be **positive**.

> *"I also tried this, but I get an empty string instead of a number"* `subAmt1 = Mid(examples, pos1 - 2, 1)`

As VBA's `Mid()` function logic counts lengths only to the right, you'll have to shift the starter position to the left; so try instead: `subAmt1 = Mid(examples, pos1 - 1, 1)` or even `subAmt1 = Trim(Mid(examples, pos1 - 2, 2))`. - As you can see this approach wouldn't allow more than 2 digits in your example.

---

If you want *partout* to allow a negative length you'd have to construct a comparable function by your own. Example call: `subAmt1 = MidX(examples, pos1, -1)` or even `subAmt1 = Trim(MidX(examples, pos1, -2))` with the same restriction as above as you don't know the exact amount of digits.

```
Function midX(s As String, Start As Long, Optional lngth As Long) As Variant
'a) Start must not exceed the string length
    If Start < 1 Or Start > Len(s) Then midX = CVErr(5): Exit Function
'b) Provide for omitted length indication (in case of positive lengths)
'   (absolute lengths exceeding the length of the resting string part
'   return the entire disponible string in both directions)
    If IsMissing(lngth) Then midX = Mid$(s, Start): Exit Function
'c) Include negative lengths via Right() function
    If lngth < 0 Then   ' negative (i.e. reverse) lngth argument in Mid function
        midX = Right$(Left$(s, Start - 1), Abs(lngth))
    Else                ' positive lngth argument returns the classical Mid function
        midX = Mid$(s, Start, lngth)
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit
' Option 1
Sub DoIt()
    Dim sTxt As String, iLoc As Long
    Dim sUnit As String, sNum As String
    sTxt = "Peter sell 1kt Gold to James"
'    sTxt = "Aplh sell 300kb of Liquid Nitrogen to Liz" ' for testing
    iLoc = InStr(sTxt, "kt")
    If iLoc Then
        sUnit = "kt"
        sTxt = Left(sTxt, iLoc - 1)
        iLoc = InStrRev(sTxt, " ")
        sNum = Mid(sTxt, iLoc)
    Else
        iLoc = InStr(sTxt, "kb")
        If iLoc Then
            sUnit = "kb"
            sTxt = Left(sTxt, iLoc - 1)
            iLoc = InStrRev(sTxt, " ")
            sNum = Mid(sTxt, iLoc)
        End If
    End If
    Debug.Print sNum, sUnit
End Sub

' Option 2
Sub DoIt2()
    Dim sTxt As String
    Dim sUnit As String, sNum As String
    Dim aTxt, i As Long
    sTxt = "Peter sell 1kt Gold to James"
'    sTxt = "Aplh sell 300kb of Liquid Nitrogen to Liz" ' for testing
    aTxt = Split(sTxt)
    For i = 0 To UBound(aTxt)
        If aTxt(i) Like "*k?" Then
            sNum = Left(aTxt(i), Len(aTxt(i)) - 2)
            sUnit = Right(aTxt(i), 2)
            If (sUnit = "kt" Or sUnit = "kb") And IsNumeric(sNum) Then
                Debug.Print sNum, sUnit
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

- btw, you can use `Mid(examples, pos1 - 1, 1)` to get the digit

```
examples = "Peter sell 1kt Gold to James"
'Get Unit and Amount
ID = "kt"
pos1 = InStr(examples, ID)

Dim subAmt1 As String
subAmt1 = Mid(examples, pos1 - 1, 1)
Debug.Print subAmt1
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Mid function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Answer (score 0):

### Parse Data

[image]

```vb
Sub ParseAmountUnit()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim srg As Range:
    Set srg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = ws.Range("B2")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dcell.Resize(rCount, 2)
    
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 2)
    
    Dim r As Long, n As Long, IsDigitFound As Boolean, IsUnitFound As Boolean
    Dim Sentence As String, Char As String, Digits As String, Unit As String
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        ' Read.
        Sentence = CStr(sData(r, 1))
        ' Loop and build.
        For n = 1 To Len(Sentence)
            Char = Mid(Sentence, n, 1)
            If Char Like "#" Then
                If IsUnitFound Then
                    Unit = Unit & Char
                Else
                    If Not IsDigitFound Then IsDigitFound = True
                    Digits = Digits & Char
                End If
            ElseIf Char = " " Then
                If IsDigitFound Then Exit For
            Else
                If IsDigitFound Then
                    If Not IsUnitFound Then IsUnitFound = True
                    Unit = Unit & Char
                End If
            End If
        Next n
        If IsDigitFound Then
            ' Write.
            dData(r, 1) = CLng(Digits)
            dData(r, 2) = Unit
            ' Reset.
            IsDigitFound = False
            IsUnitFound = False
            Digits = vbNullString
            Unit = vbNullString
        End If
    Next r
                    
    drg.Value = dData
                
End Sub
```